# VBA to goal seek with loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

Basically I need some goal seek from C5 to H15 referring to AF5 to AK15 by changing cell AX5 to BC15
A = 0, B = 10
A_2 = 0, B_2 = 5
But code below didn't working, this didnt work when I'm adding the y variable inside the code

Invalid Next control variable reference is the error that appear when run the macro

```
Sub GoalSeek()

A = [A]
B = [B]
A_2 = [A_2]
B_2 = [B_2]

x = St
y = St_2

For x = St To En
For y = St_2 To En_2

Cells(5 + x, 3 + y).GoalSeek Goal:=Cells(5 + x, 32 + y), ChangingCell:=Cells(5 + x, 50 + y)

Next x
Next y
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify "didn't work" ... do you get an error (which number and text, on which line) or does the code not not provide the expected result (what result do you get vs expected result?)

Comment: Invalid Next control variable reference

Comment: Use `Next` without a variable

Comment: `Next y   Next x` nested loop is crossover

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome so what's the fix here? so next y code 1st then next x?

Comment: @rotabor will check on this, but if I simply use next, so xthe macro will finish x loop then starting to y loop or?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome I tried this, still cant functioning, still invalid reference if i simply change next y and next x order

Comment: pls share your sample data as Markdown table in OP. What is the value of st, en, st_2, en_2?

Comment: Using a variable name with `Next` is extra, anyway the `Next` closes the previous `For` only. But in your case, you can close both loops in a single line: `Next y, x`. Variable order should be in reverse order as with two separate `Next`.